Is the Drinfeld element of a semisimple quasitriangular Hopf algebra invariant under the Drinfeld twist?
Let $A$ be a finite dimensional semisimple quasitriangular Hopf algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ with universal $R$-matrix denoted by $\mathcal{R}\in A\otimes A$. The Drinfeld element of $A$ is defined as
$$u=m(S\otimes\mathrm{id})\mathcal{R}_{21}.$$
For finite dimensional semisimple Hopf algebras, $u$ is a central element, i.e., $ux=xu$ for $x\in A$.
A Drinfeld twist for $A$ is an invertible element $J=J^{(1)}\otimes J^{(2)}\in A\otimes A$, with inverse $\bar{J}=\bar{J}^{(1)}\otimes \bar{J}^{(2)}\in A\otimes A$ satisfying
\begin{eqnarray}
    (\Delta\otimes \mathrm{id})(J)J_{12}&=&(\mathrm{id}\otimes \Delta)(J)J_{23}, \\
(\varepsilon\otimes
    \mathrm{id})(J)&=&(\mathrm{id}\otimes \varepsilon)(J)=1,\\
J\bar{J}&=&1\otimes 1,
\end{eqnarray}
where $\mathrm{id}$ is the identity map of $A$. Given a twist $J$ for $A$, we can define the twisted quasitriangular Hopf algebra
$(A^J,\Delta^J,\varepsilon^J,S^J, \mathcal{R}^J)$ as follows: $A^J=A$ as an
algebra, the coproduct, counit, antipode, and universal $R$-matrix are determined by
\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta^J(x)=J^{-1}\Delta(x)J,\quad \varepsilon^J=\varepsilon,\quad S^J(x)=w^{-1}S(x)w,\quad \mathcal{R}^J=J_{21}^{-1}\mathcal{R}J
\end{eqnarray}
for all $x\in A$, where $w=m(S\otimes \mathrm{id})J=SJ^{(1)}J^{(2)}$ is an invertible element of $A$ with $w^{-1}=\bar{J}^{(1)}S\bar{J}^{(2)}$.
Question: is the Drinfeld element of $A^J$ the same as the Drinfeld element of $A$?

The last equation should be $w^{-1} = \bar{J}^{(1)} S(\bar{J}^{(2)})$ instead.
